# Team City Setup giving warning of no agent

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I am trying to setup teamcity with Github repository.
After setting up projec, When I got "Paramater Tab", It asks some configuration parameter value. See in below screenshot.

[image]

For Now I am not giving any value and click on "Run" button on top right corner.
Then it gives some warning.

```
 Warning: No enabled compatible agents for this build configuration. 
Please register a build agent or tweak build configuration requirements.
```

[image]

What is the problem? How can I make it run?

Comment: Can you have a look at your build agent details and look at the Build runners tab and see if you have any entries there for Nuget? I suspect that you're missing Nuget on it.

Comment: @Nanhydrin  - Please look at this screenshot http://prntscr.com/mnltri

Comment: That's not what I was after Gopal, but it explains your requirement. 
I'm going to post an answer for you to try.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your agent doesn't have Nuget installed, but your build configuration requires it.

To install Nuget on the build agent:

1. In TeamCity, go to **Administration** (top right of any page).
2. Go to **Tools** in the menu down the left hand side of that page.
   You should now see a list of available tools.
3. Scroll down the list until you find **Nuget.exe** in the list.
   [image]
   You may already have multiple versions installed in which case you probably just need to click **Make Default** on one of them.
4. I you have no Nuget versions installed then click the **Install Version** button and pick the version you want to install.
5. This will distribute the Nuget tool to all build agents that can run it and it should resolve your error.

Please see this [TeamCity documentation link](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Installing+Agent+Tools) for more information.

Comment: Did you restart the agent?

Answer (score 0):

For TeamCity to run, you have to have TeamCity installed, the tooling configured (as the previous answer suggested you were missing NuGet) but you also need to install and configure build agents that can actually run the build. By default, the TeamCity instance does not install any build agents, you have to install and configure those yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the agent wasn't up, try the following:

```
cd /home/admin/TeamCity/buildAgent_latest/bin
sudo ./agent.sh start
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me.

```
C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\bin>agent.bat start
```

Looked on Teamcity help as well but did not answer the question properly. This was simple and after starting the agent from teamcity folder location the project got up and running. Thank you.